# Flagging duplicate elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of pairs of observations:

```
{a,b}
{c,d}
{e,f}
{g,h}
{i,a}
{a,d}
```

I would like to flag each pair "True" if neither of its elements appear in any other pairs in the list, and "False" otherwise:

```
{a,b,False}
{c,d,False}
{e,f,True}
{g,h,True}
{i,a,False}
{a,d,False}
```

I have written inelegant code using 3 For loops that does this, but I am confident there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: Do any pairs have the same element twice? If not, you count how many times each element occurs in the flattened list.

Comment: yes there could be pairs like that. and I like your idea, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given:

```
$pairs = { {a,b}, {c,d}, {e,f}, {g,h}, {i,a}, {a,d} };
```

We start by counting the occurrences of each element:

```
$counts = $pairs // Flatten // Counts

(* <| a -> 3, b -> 1, c -> 1 ,d -> 2, e -> 1, f -> 1, g -> 1, h -> 1, i -> 1 |> *)
```

... and then use those counts to assemble the result:

```
{#1, #2, $counts[#1] + $counts[#2] == 2} & @@@ $pairs

(* {{a,b,False},{c,d,False},{e,f,True},{g,h,True},{i,a,False},{a,d,False}} *)
```

**Update**

As noted in the question's comments (which I originally missed), there is the prospect that both elements of a pair could have the same value.  In that case, we need to add `Map[DeleteDuplicates]` to the counting stage to ensure that each pair value is only counted as belonging to one pair:

```
$pairs = { {a,b}, {c,d}, {e,f}, {g,h}, {i,a}, {a,d}, {z,z}, {i,i} };

$counts = $pairs // Map[DeleteDuplicates] // Flatten // Counts

(* <| a->3, b->1, c->1, d->2, e->1, f->1, g->1, h->1, i->2, z->1|> *)

{#1, #2, $counts[#1] + $counts[#2] == 2} & @@@ $pairs

(* { {a,b,False},{c,d,False},{e,f,True},{g,h,True}
   , {i,a,False},{a,d,False},{z,z,True},{i,i,False}
   }
*)
```

Comment: This fails for `$pairs = {{a, a}, {c, d}}`

Comment: @mikado Whoops, I missed your comment under the question.  Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Don't know if your lists are going to be large, but if so, the performance of this s/b decent:

```
mark = Module[{base = ArrayPad[#, {{0, 0}, {0, 1}}, True]},
    base[[Union @@ Cases[Ceiling[Values[PositionIndex[Flatten[#]]]/2], {_, __}], 3]] = False;
    base] &;
```

Usage:

```
result=mark@listOfPairs
```

Using:

```
junk = Array[x, 100000];
list = RandomChoice[junk, {100000, 2}];
```

to generate a test list of pairs, quite a bit quicker than answers so far. If lists are really large, comment, I've some other ideas...

Comment: This fails for `listOfPairs = {{a, a}, {c, d}}`

Comment: @mikado : so do the other answers, OP did not make clear how that's to be handled, simple change w/ nil performance impact "fixes" that, so when/if OP comments, I'll add it.

Comment: Comment to OP says that duplicates can occur

Answer (score 4):

I thank @mikado for pointing out an error. I did not account for pairs such as {a,a}. I have read the comments in relation to this. I post just to correct.

```
func[x_, lst_] := Module[{c = 2},
  If[Length[Union[x]] == 1, c = 1];
  Length[Flatten[Intersection[#, x] & /@ lst]] == c]
pairs[lst_] := {##, func[{##}, lst]} & @@@ lst
```

Testing on:

```
dat0 = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}, {i, a}, {a, d}};
dat1 = {{a, a}, {c, d}};
dat2 = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}, {i, a}, {a, d}, {z, z}, {i, 
    i}};
Grid[{#, pairs[#]} & /@ {dat0, dat1, dat2}, Alignment -> Left, 
 Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: This fails for `dat = {{a, a}, {c, d}} `

Comment: @mikado thank you . A stupid mistake by me. Appreciate you pointing it out.

Answer (score 4):

```
data = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}, {i, a}, {a, d}};

Table[
  {Sequence @@ data[[n]], ContainsNone[Flatten@Drop[data, {n}], data[[n]]]},
  {n, 1, Length[data]}
]
```

> {{a, b, False}, {c, d, False}, {e, f, True}, {g, h, True}, {i, a, 
>     False}, {a, d, False}}

Answer (score 3):

**DisjointQ**

```
pairs = { {a,b}, {c,d}, {e,f}, {g,h}, {i,a}, {a,d} };

Append[#, DisjointQ[Flatten @ Complement[pairs, {#}], #]]& /@ pairs
```

> {{a, b, False}, {c, d, False}, {e, f, True}, {g, h, True}, {i, a, 
>     False}, {a, d, False}}

**ConnectedComponents + TransitiveReductionGraph + RelationGraph + IntersectingQ**

```
byitselfQ = Join @@ (If[Length @ # == 1, Thread[# -> True], Thread[ # -> False]]&/@  
 ConnectedComponents @ TransitiveReductionGraph[RelationGraph[IntersectingQ, #]])&;

byitselQ @ pairs
```

> {{a, b} -> False, {i, a} -> False, {a, d} -> False, {c, d} -> 
>         False, {g, h} -> True, {e, f} -> True}

Organize into the desired form:

```
Append @@@ byitselQ[pairs]
```

> {{a, b, False}, {i, a, False}, {a, d, False}, {c, d, False}, {g, h, 
>         True}, {e, f, True}}

If the order is important, you can use

```
rubeGoldbergF[l_]:= Append[#, #/. byitselQ[l]]& /@ l;
rubeGoldbergF @ pairs
```

> {{a, b, False}, {c, d, False}, {e, f, True}, {g, h, True}, {i, a, 
>         False}, {a, d, False}}

Answer (score 2):

Someone will almost certainly have an even simpler way than this

```
pairs = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}, {i, a}, {a, d}};
Table[xx = pairs[[nn]]; Append[xx, Intersection[Flatten[
  Drop[pairs, {nn}]], xx] == {}], {nn, Length[pairs]}]
```

(* {{a,b,False}, {c,d,False}, {e,f,True}, {g,h,True}, {i,a,False}, {a,d,False}} *)

Answer (score 2):

```
pairs = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}, {i, a}, {a, d}, {z, z}, {i, i}};

dup = Cases[Rule[a_, b_] /; Length[b] > 1 :> a] @
  Normal @ PositionIndex @ Flatten @ Map[DeleteDuplicates] @ pairs
```

{a, d, i}

```
Transpose[{pairs, ContainsNone[#, dup] & /@ pairs}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `Table`, `Intersection` and `DeleteCases`:

```
data = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}, {i, a}, {a, d}, {z, z}, {i, i}};

rule = Rule[x_, y_] :> If[Length[y] == 0, 
       {Sequence @@ x, True}, {Sequence @@ x, False}];

Thread@Rule[data, Map[Intersection[#[[1]], Flatten@#[[2]]] &, 
Table[{data[[m]], DeleteCases[data, data[[m]]]}, {m, 1, 
Length[data]}]]] /. rule // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Or more compact:

```
rule = {a_, b_} :> If[! IntersectingQ[a, b], 
{Sequence @@ a, True}, {Sequence @@ a, False}]

Table[{#[[m]], Flatten@DeleteCases[#, #[[m]]]}, {m, Length[#]}] &@data /. rule
```

[image]

Comment: Please run it with `data = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}, {i, a}, {a, d}, {z, z}, {i, 
    i}};` used by @eldo.

Comment: Thanks mate! I had to change to something more readable to get the correct result. :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Using `TakeList`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
data = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}, {i, a}, {a, d}, {z, z}, {i, 
    i}};

Transpose[{data,
   Not@*IntersectingQ @@@
    (Map[Union, #, {1}] & /@ 
      Map[Flatten[#, 
          1] &] /@ (TakeList[data, {{#}, {1, Length@data - 1}}] & /@ 
         Range@Length@data)
     )
   }
  ] // Grid
```

---

*Result*

[image]

---

*Explanation*

1- The `TakeList` step separates the tuple to be compared to the rest of the list.

2- These two lists per row are subjected to `Union` before `IntersectingQ` determines overlap.

3- The `Transpose` step is for visualization only.

Answer (score 2):

```
flagDistinct = MapIndexed[{$v, $i} |-> {Splice @ $v, 
           ContainsNone[$v] @ Flatten @ Drop[#, $i]}] @ # &;
```

***Example:***

```
pairs = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}, {i, a}, {a, d}, {z, z}, {i, i}};

flagDistinct @ pairs // Column
```

[image]